# IE Performance issue - slow

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drupal

I am having an issue with my site loading properly as its just so slow on all IE and i dont know why, i have the jquery, css and everything compressed.

Would anyone know why this would be happening?

http://puragen.co.uk

Thanks again for your help.

Comment: I don't see any problem using IE9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`YSLOW`](http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/) or [`Google Page Speed`](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/) tool to analyse your site and it will help you to fix performance issues.

There are more thn 2 MB of images loaded in home page that's pretty big. Try compressing the images to reduce file size (image sprite is recommended).

Here's the online tool to compress images file size, [Smush.it](http://www.smushit.com/ysmush.it/)

I assume it's Drupal website, then try look for performance modules which will boost the performance on the backend.

Comment: Thank you very much. I am using these methods and reducing the sizes of the images on the website.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your IE has a lot of add-ons plugged in? Any antivirus scans on pages? I know IE's performance is greatly affected by these. There is nothing you can do if you are concerned about which browser your customers are using but if there are no errors being logged in the developer tools (F12) then you cannot do anything.

Maybe try to increase the use of caching to speed up performance? But I cannot see anything wrong in IE. Try other versions and other peoples machines for testing.

A good cross browser tool I use is [spoon.net](http://spoon.net) but it is not a free service

Answer (score 1):

It is long since you transport about 2.9 Mb of data over the network! And it seems to be mainly images...

You should compress first your images ([Yahoo! Smushit](http://www.smushit.com/ysmush.it/) or [tinypng](http://tinypng.org/), ...), use sprites and so on...

Answer (score 1):

As an addition to the other answers I would recommend using a profiler to see where your bottleneck exacly is.

I can recommend using [firebug](https://getfirebug.com/javascript) but there are several other applications around.
With using a profiler you can see how long it takes to load your images and how your javascript execution performace is.